# How fix "cannot find symbol" in my code?

Tags: java

first off apologies for such a basic question as I am brand new to coding.

I understand the concept of my errors below  (that I must define item within my scope for the getItemSize method) but I've tried different ways that only prompt more errors.  The errors are:

GuessingGame.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
    Jar jar = new Jar(item, jarSize);
                      ^
  symbol:   variable item
  location: class GuessingGame
GuessingGame.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
    Jar jar = new Jar(item, jarSize);
                            ^
  symbol:   variable jarSize
  location: class GuessingGame
./Prompter.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
                      item);
                      ^
  symbol:   variable item
  location: class Prompter
3 errors"

Here is my code for the Prompter class:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Prompter {
      private Jar jar;
    public Prompter (Jar jar) {
      this.jar = jar; 
    }

    public String promptForItem() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.printf("---ADMIN SETTINGS---%n");
    System.out.printf("What type of item should go in the jar?  ");
    String item = scanner.nextLine();
    return item;
    }

    public String promptForSize() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.printf("What is the maximum amount of %s?%n  ", 
                      item);
    String jarSize = scanner.nextLine();
    return jarSize;
    } 

   }
```

And my code for the Game.class:

```
 public class GuessingGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Jar jar = new Jar(item, jarSize);
    Prompter prompter = new Prompter(jar);
      prompter.promptForItem();
      prompter.promptForSize();
    }
}
```

How can I go about resolving these errors?  I've tried different ways but no luck.  Thank you!

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to include my Jar.java file.  Here it is:

```
public class Jar {
  private String item;
  private String jarSize;

  public Jar(String item, String jarSize) {
    this.item = item;
    this.jarSize = jarSize;
}
}
```

Comment: Did you Google the error in order to make an effort to understand what the error is, why it happens, and how it might be fixed? Hint: How and why should your program know what a `Jar` is?

Comment: The compiler is expecting there to be a class named "Jar" in the current project.  Have you defined this class?  Is it on the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

You have to fix your inputs. All the things like `Jar` must be imported. For example:

```
import mpackage.Jar;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things :

First, `GuessingGame` doesn't know what the `Jar` class is because the import statement is missing (in the following code, I assume the package where `Jar` lies is called `yourpackage`)

Then, you are attempting to create a `Jar` instance by passing two variables (`item` and `jarSize`) which are undefined in `GuessingGame`.

You probably wanted to use the `Prompter` class to obtain them (note that the constructor taking a `Jar` has been removed, I can't see why you would have a `Jar` in the `Prompter`class) :

```
 import yourpackage.Jar;

 public class GuessingGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Prompter prompter = new Prompter();
    String item =   prompter.promptForItem();
    String jarSize = prompter.promptForSize();
    Jar jar = new Jar(item, jarSize);

    }
}
```

The `Prompter` class :

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Prompter {

    public String promptForItem() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.printf("---ADMIN SETTINGS---%n");
    System.out.printf("What type of item should go in the jar?  ");
    String item = scanner.nextLine();
    return item;
    }

    public String promptForSize() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.printf("What is the maximum amount of %s?%n  ", 
                      item);
    String jarSize = scanner.nextLine();
    return jarSize;
    } 

}
```